# Symfony 2 : Validate form for defined fields only

Tags: forms, symfony

Is it possible to validate only present fields of the form..

For example, I have a declarationForm, I give rules in the validation.yml for 3 fields : name, reference, commantary.. sometime I dont add commentary field in my builder. Anyway when I validate the form it says that commentary cannot be empty (but there is no field commentary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you will have to remove the `NotBlank` conditions from your `validation.yml` for the `commentary` field and add the requirement back into the builder whenever you include it in your `FormBuilderInterface`:

```
$builder
    // ... other fields using add()
    ->add('commentary', 'text', array(
        'required' => true,
    ))
;
```

Note however that this does indeed only add an HTML5 `required` attribute to both the `input` and `label` tags.

The better solution thanks to @Cerad is to [add validation groups to your `validation.yml`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups) for the field:

```
AcmeBundle\Entity\Declaration: # change to your entity class
    properties:
        # ...
        commentary:
            - NotBlank: { groups: [commentaryReq] }
```

And then [use the Form Builder with this validation group](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#validation-groups) when needed:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($declaration, array(
    'validation_groups' => array('commentaryReq'),
))
    //->add(...)
;
```

or if you're using Form Classes:

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => array('commentaryReq'),
    ));
}
```

You can also [specify groups based on submitted data](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#groups-based-on-the-submitted-data) or [specify groups based on the button that was clicked](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#groups-based-on-the-clicked-button) if that helps.

Comment: I suspect that using validation groups http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups would be cleaner.  That way he has the option of validating commentary when he needs to.

Comment: sorry but this does not work. Tell me if I am wrong but this is not a Symfony 2 validation but a html5 validation...it does not work with ie8 and anyway I disabled html5 validation in my forms

Comment: @ mlwacosmos - You are wrong.  HTML validation is only going to apply to input elements that are actually present in your html form.  Based on your question, this is absolutely not the case.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you, completely forgot about that. I've updated my answer with your suggestions and sample code for OP

Comment: @Cerad OP is also correct in his statement because [the docs state](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#required) "If true, an HTML5 required attribute will be rendered. [...] This is superficial and independent from validation."

Comment: Right but his question indicates that his form builder does not have a commentary field at all while his comment indicates that he thinks HTML5 validation is the culprit.  At least that is the way I interpreted it.  Let's see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow empty `commentary` field, add `nullable=true` to its column definition in your entity:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#property-mapping