# Symfony2 Form Validation - Apply conditional validation_group

Tags: symfony

Is there a way to enforce a different validation group based on the selected value in a form?  For example, if I have payment info form and "credit card" is selected, then I would apply the "credit_card" validation group.  If it wasn't, then I'd apply the default validation group.  I know how to set the validation group when creating a form, however, I don't know how to dynamically set it based on a form's values.

I'm trying to avoid using callbacks because I want to use Symfony's built-in validators.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can do this in the setDefaultOptions method of your form:

```
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => 'IRC\GlobalBundle\Form\Entity\Checkout\OrderPayment',
                'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form) {
                    /** @var PaymentType $paymentType */
                    $paymentType = $form->getData()->getPaymentType();
                    if ($paymentType->getId() === PaymentType::CREDIT_CARD) {
                        return array('credit_card');
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: Yes, [here's another SO question with my answer addressing your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26491121/1188035)